# Simplify a powerset function in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to simplify to following function as much as possible:

```
public string[] GetPowerSet(string input)
    {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> seed = new List<IEnumerable<string>>() { Enumerable.Empty<string>() };

        return input.Split(',').ToList().Aggregate(seed, (a, b) =>
          a.Concat(a.Select(x => x.Concat(new List<string>() { b })))).Select(subset => string.Join(",", subset.ToArray())).Skip(1).ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say I've simplified it much... but I've removed some syntactic extras that were unnecessary in the original version, made the method itself static (no reliance on instance data or methods) and hoisted out the seed to a one-time initialized class-level variable for speed/GC (over multiple calls) sake:

```
private static readonly IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> seed =
    new List<IEnumerable<string>> { Enumerable.Empty<string>() };

public static string[] GetPowerSet(string input)
{
    return input.Split(',').Aggregate(
        seed,
        (a, b) => a.Concat(a.Select(x => x.Concat(new[] { b })))).Select(subset => string.Join(",", subset)).Skip(1).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Man, it's been quite a while since I've had to deal with powerset.  I don't really know what your code is doing, but you could simplify it and make it more readable by creating some general utility functions and with some thoughtful use of whitespace.  Below is the best I can come up with:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> source, string separator)
    {
        using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(enumerator.Current);

                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    builder.Append(separator).Append(enumerator.Current);
                }

                return builder.ToString();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, T second)
    {
        foreach (var item in first)
        {
            yield return item;
        }

        yield return second;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, params T[] second)
    {
        foreach (var item in first)
        {
            yield return item;
        }

        foreach (var item in second)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}

public static class PowerSet
{
    public static string[] GetPowerSet(string input)
    {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> seed = new List<IEnumerable<string>>() { Enumerable.Empty<string>() };

        return input.Split(',').Aggregate(
                seed,
                (a, b) => a.Concat(
                    a.Select(x => x.Append(b))
                )
            ).Select(
                subset => subset.Join(",")
            ).Skip(1).ToArray();
    }
}
```